# how to grouped column and get max value of these repeated

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have column has repeated values, I want to group them and get the max value of these grouped because the column has Repeated values, so I want to know how many the value has repeated then get the max value from these grouped values

[image: Like this clarification]

Comment: please share sample data and expected output as a text not image please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use your `Group By` query results in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and then determine the [`Max()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) Value.

Try:

```
SELECT MAX(dt.total) 
FROM 
( 
  SELECT COUNT(letter_f_id) AS total 
  FROM scop_letter 
  GROUP BY letter_f_id 
) AS dt
```

Comment: Thank you that's my I want, it's work ^_^, I want the max value to repeat the table <heade> according to the max value showing in the <body> table

Answer (score 0):

I know sql-server a lot better than MySQL, so I wrote the query in that. Still should be pretty straightforward to convert to MySQL. 
It seems like you want the max value of another query. That can be accomplished by adding a subquery to your main query. You select the max value of a query which returns the count of another grouped-by row, as depicted below:

```
SELECT [letter_f_id], MAX(Total)
FROM
    (SELECT [letter_f_id]
           , COUNT([letter_f_id]) AS 'Total'
    FROM [YourTable]
    GROUP BY [letter_f_id])
GROUP BY [letter_f_id]
```

Comment: I post the desired result as an image because accomplish steps query to get the last result

Comment: Revised the post